# NaiveBayesClassifier vs SklearnClassifier

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I'm using both nltk NaiveBayesClassifier and SklearnClassifier for classification of sentences. Is there is a way to find which is the best classification. For eg: If i give "You are looking not so great" , one is classifying it as "Positive" and other as "Negative". I just want to know which is correct or which is more accurate than the other for that particular classification, because i will automate for more the 2k data where manual checking is tedious.

Comment: Well you should separate your training dataset in train and test and see for yourself which classifier has the best accuracy, f1-score etc... You do not need manual checking.

Comment: i was able to find the probability of classification for NaiveBayesClassifier but not for SklearnClassifier.